# Route [course] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I created a resource controller. The problem is when I code a route in my view, the browser displays Route [course] not defined.
I run the php artisan route:list command and I realize that the route does not exist in the route list.

The controller method

```
public function index()
{
    $courses = Course::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->paginate(10);

    return view('teacher.teachercourse.courses', compact('courses'));
}
```

The web.php code

```
Route::get('course', 'CoursesController@index')->name('course');
Route::get('course', 'CoursesController@create')->name('course.create');
```

The link

```
<li><a href="{{ route('course') }}">Courses</a></li>
```

Comment: You have two routes with the same path and method. You cannot have this, because the system will get confused. In this case, the second is overriding the first.

Comment: Please tag the question with the framework you use.

Comment: you have two routes.  so its taking the second one course.create.   you need to change the second to Route::post()

Answer (score 1):

As both routes are **get** you can't use the same uri:

change the uri example:

```
Route::get('courses', 'CoursesController@index')->name('courses.index');
Route::post('course/create', 'CoursesController@create')->name('course.create');
```

Comment: Thanks good, your solution solved my problem